# How to add a callback in this function for gzip

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, gzip, zlib

Here is my code:

```
/*jshint globalstrict: true*/
var zlib = require('zlib');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'});

    var text = "Hey this works!";
    zlib.gzip(text, function (_, result) {
        res.end(result);
    });
}).listen(8081);
```

I want to add a callback to the above code to follow the node.js async concept. How do I do that? Also, I am pretty new to node.js

Comment: You already added a callback. What is the actual problem? Also, you really should not ignore the `err` argument of the callback (you should at least send back an HTTP status code of 500 or similar if `err` is set).

Comment: where have I added a callback

Comment: Your callback is the function that contains `res.end(result);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var callback = function (err, result) {
    // gzip has finished, do any thing you want here,
    // also add if about the 'err' as mscdex said.
    res.end(result);
 }
 zlib.gzip(text, callback);
```

callback is a function,you already added it .